# how to update the height of a textarea in vue.js when updating the value dynamically?

Tags: vue.js

Working with Vue.js, I do use a simple way to set dynamically the height of a text area that resizes when typing. But I am not able to do it when the component mounts or the value updates.

I have already try http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/, but it has the same problem.

I have created a sandbox that shows the problem, when typing the box it updates, but not when the value changes dynamically

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/53nmll917l

[image: problem in action]

Comment: Do you need to use a slot for the textarea? Seems like a pretty easy problem to solve if you could incorporate the textarea in the component's template.

Comment: No necessarily, the text area can be included in the template as well. I did try it but without luck. The problem is that i don't know how to hook the event when the data changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `triggerInput()` method:

```
triggerInput() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.resize.$el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
  });
}
```

to use whenever you're changing the value programatically, triggering the resize logic used on `<textarea>` on "*real*" `input` events.

[Updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxokw63vx6).

**Note:** Without the `$nextTick()` wrapper, the recently changed value will not have been applied yet and, even though the `input` ***is*** triggered, the element has not yet been updated and the resize happens before `value` has changed, resulting in the old `height` and looking like it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Not really feeling the answers posted here. Here is my simple solution:

```
<textarea
   rows="1"
   ref="messageInput"
   v-model="message"
/>
```

```
watch: {
    message: function(newItem, oldItem) {
      let { messageInput } = this.$refs;
      const lineHeightInPixels = 16;
      
      // Reset messageInput Height
      messageInput.setAttribute(
          `style`,
          `height:${lineHeightInPixels}px;overflow-y:hidden;`
      );

      // Calculate number of lines (soft and hard)
      const height = messageInput.style.height;
      const scrollHeight = messageInput.scrollHeight;
      messageInput.style.height = height;
      const count = Math.floor(scrollHeight / lineHeightInPixels);

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        messageInput.setAttribute(
            `style`,
            `height:${count*lineHeightInPixels}px;overflow-y:hidden;`
        );
      });
    },
}
```

```
<style scoped>
textarea {
  height: auto;
  line-height: 16px;
}
</style>
```